# Nest Javascript Object not accepting push method. TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to push a variable into a property in a nested object, but Javascript keeps giving me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

However, if I declare a nested variable and use that to push, it works. Why does Javascript have this behavior?

Is there a way to do this without declaring the nested variable and without declaring an empty array?

```js
var collection = {
    5439: {
      albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
    }
  };

collection[5439]["track"] = [''];
console.log(collection[5439].track);
// nested = collection[5439]["track"];
// nested.push('c') // this works
// console.log(nest)
collection[5439]["tracks"].push('c');
```

Comment: Should be 'track' not 'tracks'. property tracks is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
collection[5439]["tracks"].push('c');
```

changed to: (`track` not `tracks`)

```
collection[5439]["track"].push('c');
```

Comment: Is there a way to push value into a property without first having to declare an array?

Comment: it should be an array first then you can use method `push` of array. But for more elegant way of code, you should initialize the track property `var collection = {5439: {...}, track: []}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat method for this. Just like:

```
collection[5439]["track"].concat('c');
```

Answer (score 0):

`collection[5439]["tracks"].push('c');` error is this line because `collection[5439]["tracks"]` is undefined and not an array.

Try some thing like this, initialise if not exist using `??` (nullish coalescing operator)

```js
var collection = {
    5439: {
      albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
    }
  };

(collection[5439]["tracks"] ??= []).push("hello");

console.log(collection[5439]["tracks"])
```